# Problem with Logitech C270 webcam and Usb_cam

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone, I'm new in ROS and I'm triying to use "usb_cam" for recieve images from a Logitech C270 webcam, but I have a problem with the visualizer "image_view".

I can connect with the webcam using "rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node" but when I want to see the visualizer using "rosrun image_view image_view image:=/usb_cam/image_raw", I only see a green image from the webcam. Also, I tried to visualizing the webcam images with rqt_image_view and I can see the same.

With others programs or apps in Ubuntu the image webcam it's succesfully, but in ROS I can't use the webcam without see a green image.

I've read in this forum and I've tried a lot of options for resolve my problem and I couldn't do it. For this motive, I write this post and I wonder... What's my problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288327/problem-with-logitech-c270-webcam-and-usb_cam/) by [Malatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/34600/malatesta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2018-04-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The default parameters for usb_cam are unlikely to work, you'll need to discover them and then have a rosrun like:

```
rosrun usb_cam usb_cam_node _image_width:=1280 _image_height:=720 _framerate:=15 _video_device:=/dev/video0 _pixel_format:=mjpeg
```

You can use guvcview to determine working resolutions and formats, or a command line like

```
v4l2-ctl --device=0 --list-formats-ext
```

I've written this up here (and a lot of other related ros webcam tips): https://gist.github.com/lucasw/85dc92c9f5146e9d5175a33b49ef4a90

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Malatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/34600/malatesta/) on 2018-04-13**:
Hi Lucasw, thanks for your response. I'm going to try this and find the parameters of my webcam to repeat the whole process.

**Comment by [nana](https://answers.ros.org/users/37385/nana/) on 2018-09-08**:
Hi Malatesta, did you solve the problem? tell me please becouse I'll buy this camera and use it with ros.

**Comment by [Malatesta](https://answers.ros.org/users/34600/malatesta/) on 2018-09-19**:
I couldn't solve the problem and I used another camera, but it's possible my camera didn't work correctly. You can try it with your new logitech.